# Setting headers to HttpResponse in akka

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm trying to set headers to HttpResponse

```
var response = HttpResponse()
val acrh = request.headers.filter(q => q.name() == "Access-Control-Request-Headers").head.value()
response = response.addHeader(`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`(acrh))
response = response.addHeader(`Access-Control-Request-Headers`(acrh))
```

In response I can see only "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", and I'm getting this error

```
"HTTP header 'Access-Control-Request-Headers' is not allowed in responses".
```

How can I solve this problem? I need to implement this for CORS.

Comment: Access-Control-Request-Headers is a request header (sent by the requestor) and not a response header.  Akka is filtering that header out of the response because it's not supposed to be included in a http response.  Are you sure you are using it correctly?